# How to save a global variable in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I want to save a global variable in flask, and after reading some documentation I know that 'flask.g' can do what I want, but during the test I found that the variable 'g' can't be saved like session, if I change the page in the same application, the variable 'g' miss it's attribute, after reading some documents, I found that in the previous version of flask, variable 'g' is only on the request context, but ['Starting with Flask 0.10 this is stored on the application context and no longer on the request context which means it becomes available if only the application context is bound and not yet a request.'](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.g)

So I want to know why variable 'g' can't be saved in all the pages of my application, and if I want to save a global variable which can be used in all pages, how should I do it?

thx!

Comment: If your data is persistent, why don't you use sessions?

Comment: It's a selenium variable, not only some data.

Answer (score 0):

You can save those type of variables in a separate config.py in the form of class variable and access that variable in any page by simply importing that class variable

app.py

```
from config import GetConfig

print GetConfig.var
```

config.py

```
class GetConfig:
    var=10
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Comment: yes, finally i try this way, but I still want to know why the flask.g can't save as an global variable.

Comment: okay just add global variable_name in __init__.py and access that variable_name in any file

Answer (score 0):

An alternative you could use is browser caching, you should keep you web server as stateless as possible meaning each request to the server should be totally independent hence not sharing any state.